# How to save ajax post response in to database?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

My code is here.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(){
        alert('return sent');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://remotewebsite.com/process.php",
            data: somedata;
            dataType:'text'; //or HTML, JSON, etc.
            success: function(response){
                alert(response);
                //echo what the server sent back...
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

But how can i save that response coming from remote website in to my database?
And how can i send multiple input?

Comment: you can call another ajax request when you first is a success. in your second ajax save the data then return a success alert. I am not sure if this will be slow just my thoughts

Comment: I dont need speed, but how can i do that second request ?

Comment: create another ajax just like what you have and use `response` as data use post method and save it to database

Comment: you can have something like this `$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://remotewebsite.com/process.php",
    data: somedata;
    dataType: 'text'; //or HTML, JSON, etc.
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "youphppagewhereyoudothesavingindatabase",
            data: response;
            dataType: 'text'; //or HTML, JSON, etc.
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                alert("Saved in database")
            }
        });
    }
});`

Comment: Thank You for your help, can u post it as answer so i can flag it as correct answer ? :)

Comment: I posted it as answer

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://remotewebsite.com/process.php",
    data: somedata;
    dataType: 'text'; //or HTML, JSON, etc. 
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "youphppagewhereyoudothesavingindatabase",
            data: response;
            dataType: 'text'; //or HTML, JSON, etc. 
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                alert("Saved in database")
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Have it something like this